# Angularjs Set data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use a global info in my project.

I try to do like this:

```
app.service('userData',function(){

    var data;
   this.set = function(value) {
        return data = value;
    }

    this.data = function() {
        return data;
    }

});
```

But if I do refresh on the page, I lost it.

What's the best way to do it?

Thanks,
Knot

Comment: Do you use ngRouter or ui-router?

Comment: Do you mean page refresh like F5 refresh?

Comment: Yeah.. F5 refresh the page...

Comment: Yes, I'm using ui-router..

Comment: All JS variables that you create exists only within one page. So when you refresh the page your whole Angular application instance no longer exists and new one is created. Easiest way to persist such values would be to use localStorage.

Comment: Great... I got it.. I'll try it.. thanks  a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage or cookies for keeping data.